# How to filter python dictionary by another dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a method that, Looks through each value in the mainDict, returning an array of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in filterDict.

```
def where(mainDicts, filterDict):
    pass

mydicts = [{'title': "title 1", 'author': "author 1", 'year': 1611},
           {'title': "title 2", 'author': "author 2", 'year': 1615},
           {'title': "title 3", 'author': "author 1", 'year': 1611}]

filterDict = {'year': 1611, 'author': "author 1"}

where(mydicts, filterDict)
```

i want to return this:

```
[{'title': "title 1", 'author': "author 1", 'year': 1611},
 {'title': "title 3", 'author': "author 1", 'year': 1611}]
```

Comment: Could you post your attempts at an implementation?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Kindly make an attempt and post any errors that you might be facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you run Python 3:

```
def where(mainDicts, filterDict):
    return [x for x in mainDicts if not filterDict.items() - x.items()]
```

Quoting the documentation:

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable.
>   If all values are hashable, so that `(key, value)` pairs are unique and
>   hashable, then the items view is also set-like. For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class *collections.abc.Set* are available (for example, `==`, `<`, or `^`).

Refer to [Dictionary view objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) for more information.
If you need this to work in Python 2, just replace `items()` with [`viewitems()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems).

Example:

```
In [8]: where(mydicts, {'year': 1611, 'author': "author 1"})
Out[8]: 
[{'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'title 1'},
 {'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'title 3'}]
```

Note that the above won't work if your values are not hashable (see the [Glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=hashable)), but the following will

```
def where(dicts, filt):
    return [x for x in dicts if all(k in x and x[k] == v for k, v in filt.items())]
```

Comment: Nice! But IMHO `if filterDict.items() <= x.items()` is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list comprehension, for each item `d` checking whether all the keys `k` from the `filterDict` are in that item, and if so, whether the value `v` is the same.

```
def where(mainDict, filterDict):
    return [d for d in mainDict if all(k in d and d[k] == v 
                                       for k, v in filterDict.items())]
```

This also works with Python 2. Example:

```
>>> where(mydict, {'year': 1611, 'author': "author 1"})
[{'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'title 1'}, 
 {'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'title 3'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a more pythonic way you can use [`dict.viewitems`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewitems) to get the intersection between your dictionaries and the filter dictionary then if the intersection was equal with filter you can return it :

```
>>> filt={'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611}
>>> [d for d in mydict if dict(filt.viewitems()&d.viewitems())==filt]
[{'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'title 1'}, {'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'title 3'}]
```

read more about dictionary-view-objects https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, maybe it's more readable for you. It's python 2 and 3 compatible and pretty straight forward.

```
def where(list_of_dicts, filterDict):

    result = [] # to be returned, a list of dicts

    for d in list_of_dicts:
        n = 0 # count how many key/value pairs matches with filterDict
        for key in filterDict:
            try: # in case key is missing
                if d[key] == filterDict[key]:
                    n += 1
            except:
                pass # change with a proper error message
        if n == len(filterDict): # if True then all the key/value pairs in filterDict are in d
            result.append(d)

    return result




mydicts = [{'title': "title 1", 'author': "author 1", 'year': 1611},
          {'title': "title 2", 'author': "author 2", 'year': 1615},
          {'title': "title 3", 'author': "author 1", 'year': 1611}]

filterDict = {'year': 1611, 'author': "author 1"}


a = where(mydicts, filterDict)
print(a)
```

It prints out:

```
[{'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'title 1'}, {'author': 'author 1', 'year': 1611, 'title': 'title 3'}]
```

Comment: `d[key]` will fail (raise an exception) if the key is not in the dictionary.

Comment: Done :) now should be ok. Thank you for the notification.